# How to get a part of a string from the start to a specific point

Tags: python, string, split

I'm working in python and I'm trying to find a way to get part of a substring from the start to a point.

this function takes user input so I cannot use anything that relies on a set index.

some examples for input would be john.doe@gmail.com
where I'm trying to get 'john'

or wheres.waldo@yahoo.com
for the output 'wheres'

here's what I have now

```
getnamelast= s[s.index('.')+1:s.index('@')]
print(getnamelast)
```

which I know only return everything after '.'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify the goal here? Are you trying to get everything that exists prior to the first `.`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the first name (from start of the string till `.`), you can use `str.split`. For example:

```py
s = "john.doe@gmail.com"

name = s.split(".")[0]
print(name)
```

Prints:

```
john
```

Answer (score -1):

Try regex

```
firstname = re.findall(r'^[\w]*', s)
print(firstname)
```

Comment: Don't use `findall` since you're only expecting one match. You could use `match` instead. Also the character class is redundant. `firstname = re.match(r'\w*', s).group()`